# set cookie in theme header.php based on page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, wordpress-theming, setcookie

I'm trying to set a cookie in my wordpress theme header.php file.

I've found a bit of information about this but it all seems to use the functions.php file, this isn't really an option for me as I'm setting the cookie based on the page.

I'm just wondering how I could go about doing this, or what a possible work around might be.

Here's my code from my header.php file.

```
<?
// Set cookie
if (is_page('437')) {
  setcookie("DM", "mis", time()+31536000);
} else if (is_page('441')) {
  setcookie("DM", "w2p", time()+31536000);
}

echo $_COOKIE["DM"];
print_r($_COOKIE);

// Check cookie to load style
if (!is_front_page()){ 
  if (isset($_COOKIE["DM"])) {
    if ($_COOKIE["DM"] == "mis") { ?>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/mis.css" />
  <? } else if ($_COOKIE["DM"] == "w2p") { ?>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/w2p.css" />
   <? }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the cookie, queues it up to be sent to the client, but doesn't add it to the $_COOKIE array.  I believe the $_COOKIE array is only constucted and populated once--at the initial request time.  Any  cookie you want to get to goes to the client and is sent back in the following request for the next page and is then available.

Comment: I should add that the cookie does work when viewing page 437 or 441, but once I navigate to another page the cookie doesn't seem to have a value but I haven't done anything to remove its value.

Comment: I'd check to see if they're not being set at an earlier request.  From the PHP.net manual "Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also exist in $_REQUEST. "  ---> a set cookie requires a new page load as far as I know.

Comment: @Adam and this too: Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.